# Sqlite 3 Trigger error

Tags: php, ios, sqlite

I have a sqlite database that I share between a php/PDO website and Xcode for iPad/iPhone. When I create text entries on the website, PDO adds slashes which I can remove later using php's stripslashes() function. However, I need to occasionally copy the sqlite file to Xcode, but I don't want those slashes appearing in my data. Preferably, I'd like a trigger that would remove them in sqlite. I've tried

```
CREATE TRIGGER StripSlashes AFTER UPDATE OF notes ON myTable
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE myTable SET notes = replace(notes, '\', '') WHERE id=NEW.id;
END;
```

When I update the notes field, Sqlite returns the following error: "Wrong number of arguments to function REPLACE()"
However, the query:

```
SELECT replace(notes, '\', '') FROM myTable
```

works as expected.

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to do it in SQLite but you can definitely do it in Objective-C using stringByReplacingOccurencesOfString, something like this (which I haven't tested!):

```
    NSString yourstring = [yournotes stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\" withString:@""];
```

Also stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet might work too.

Comment: Thanks! I will probably need to implement something like that in my data access class if I can't resolve the SQLite issue.